# Create Contacts by Java SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, java, enterprise-wsdl

I'm trying to create one or more contacts by Java SOAP Enterprise API but I'm getting error.
This is the code:

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
      Contact c = new Contact();
      c.setFirstName("aaaa");
      c.setLastName("bbbb");
      c.setTitle(""+i);
      c.setDepartment(""+i);
      c.setBirthdate(null);
      c.setReportsToId(null);
      c.setLeadSource(""+i);
      c.setMailingAddress(null);
      c.setDescription(""+i);
      c.setHomePhone(""+i);
      c.setMobilePhone(""+i);
      c.setFax(""+i);
      c.setEmail("aaa"+i+"@bbb.com");

      contacts[i] = c;
  }
```

And this is the error:

```
`[InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE' exceptionMessage='Must send a concrete entity type.' extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'] row='-1' column='-1']]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is your array of exactly length 5? Leaving null (empty) entries in the array by having an array larger than 5 can produce that error (if the comment on this question [Update user object using SOAP Api](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133747/update-user-object-using-soap-api) is correct).

Comment: Yes @KeithC , I did a `System.out.println(contacts.length);` and it returned `5`.

Comment: @KeithC : what is d relation of array size to this error. i think each array record will be having value not null. yes, but some field would be null.

Comment: @Ankuli yep, Fields can be `null` but I think @KeithC said like an `Array a = new Array[5]` with `a[4] = null`

Comment: My concern was that if the array was say 8 long, the last 3 values would be left null because values are only being set for the first 5.

Comment: As I through... Do you know what else can be?

Comment: Someone Solved the problem? I'm still in same error

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when you're getting this error, but could it be that you're not setting the AccountId on the Contact object and it's required?

Comment: Could you maybe add any further detail to back up your hypothesis?